# Is there a limit or not?

Tags: calculus

I am practicing limits right now. I am getting confused all the time. If I got that limit is equal to infinity then limit does not exist? 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x\bigg)= ?$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\bigg(\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x\bigg)=?$$ 
 I got that limit of both is equal to infinity. I think I have a mistake.
Can you help me with limits

Comment: the second one is infinity if  it stands so

Comment: That's correct, both limits are infinite. In the first case ($x>0$), $\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x\ge2x-x=x$, in the second ($x<0$) $\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x\ge -x$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector does this mean that limit does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

write $$\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x)(\sqrt{4x^2+x}+x)}{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+x}$$
and then write
$$\frac{x^2(3+\frac{1}{x})}{|x|\left(\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}+1\right)}$$
we get in both cases $\infty$

Comment: I did wrote that and I got that 3(x^2) + x at the top

Answer (score 0):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a very simple way forward that relies on the definition of the limit and an elementary inequality.  To that end we proceed.**

Note that for any number $B>0$, however large, we have for $x>0$

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x&>2x-x\\\\
&=x\\\\
&>B
\end{align}$$

whenever $x>B$.  Hence, by the definition of the limit, we find

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{4x^2+x}-x=\infty$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.